# How to assign a Foreign Key Value in Laravel efficiently

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I just started playing with Laravel last night, I'm coming into it with experience using the Django Framework for python.

So there's quite a few similarities and I'm really quite impressed so far.

However, I'm having some difficulty understanding how to effectively assign a foreign key value to table.

For example, I have two models.

```
User
Order
```

Order will have a foreign key value to User.
    Order
        - Has Foreign Key to User, titled user_id

What I expect to be able to do, coming from Django, is I can get the currently authenticated user and assign it directly to the foreign key value using something like this...

```
$order->user = Auth::user();
```

or

```
$order->user_id = Auth::user();
```

However, this doesn't work... 
What does work is if I manually get the user_id like so...

```
$order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

It just seems to me that there should exist the ability for Laravel to just recognize that I want the id of the User object due to the Foreign key definition without me having to specify it... Like in Django.

Does Laravel support something like this, and if so how is it implemented?
I'm using Laravel 5.0

Comment: I'm quite new to laravel myself but coming from other languages I think most efficient is the method you don't want to use: $order->user_id = $uid;

what you are trying to do may be possible with laravel but convenience usually adds overhead so it is not as efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a HasMany <-> BelongsTo relationship between your User and Orders.

If so, then the most efficient way to set the actual order to the user is by doing as follow :

```
$user->orders()->associate($order);
```

You have to have the `orders()` method in your User class like this :

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Path\To\Your\Models\Order');
}
```

For more, see : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Comment: Ah ha! That sounds like it would do the trick. So then if I want to access all of the users orders I would just do something like...

$user->orders().all(); right?

Comment: $user->orders()->get(), and yes. But laravel does implements some magicals functions behind the scene. calling $user->orders() (with parentheses) will create a query builder and then you are calling ->get() from that query builder. But $user->orders (withOUT parentheses) will gives you the actual Collection of your urser's orders. It's easier to get all the collection like this.

Comment: Great stuff, can't wait to get home and try this. Thanks for the help!